# Unity not working with amdgpu-pro in 16.04 LTS

Tags: unity, 16.04, amd-graphics

I decided to install the amd-gpupro drivers because Kerbal Space Program was lagging severely. After putting `radeon.modeset=0` into the kernel parameters in /etc/default/grub and putting `amdgpu` in /etc/modules I rebooted my machine. Openbox works great with the drivers but when I tried to login to unity all I got was a desktop with icons. There is no dash, no sidebar, no window title bars, and no system bar. How do I fix this?

I have an AMD A4-6300 APU with Radeon HD Graphics and Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe.

My kernel version is 4.4.0-24-generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this easily by deleting the `amdgpu-pro` drivers altogether and updating my kernel to `4.6-generic`. Unity and my graphics intensive applications now work perfectly.